# Coloring elements of a block of a matrix

Tags: math-mode, color, matrices

Assume I have the matrix

`A = [
      a_11 a_12 a_13 a_14;
      a_21 a_22 a_23 a_24;
      a_31 a_23 _a33 a_34;
]`

where `a_ij` are numbers and I want to draw in red color the elements of the `3 x 3` block `A(1:3, 1:3)`. Is there an easy way to draw them at once instead of using the command `\textcolor{red}{a_11}`, `\textcolor{red}{a_22}` e.t.c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX is a macro language. The lengthy expression `\textcolor{red}{a_{12}}` can be abbreviated with as simple macro definition, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
  \[
    A =
    \def\ba#1#2{a_{#1#2}}
    \def\ra{\color{red}\ba}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \ra11 & \ra12 & \ra13 & \ba14 \\
      \ra21 & \ra22 & \ra23 & \ba24 \\
      \ra31 & \ra32 & \ra33 & \ba34
    \end{bmatrix}
  \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

### Update

You can declare a new column type including the color:

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\color{red}}c}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[
\begin{array}{*{3}{E}c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
7 & 8 & 9 & 0 
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be done using [`collcell`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collcell):

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand\ColCell[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1>0?1:0}%
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax\color{red}\fi#1}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\ColCell}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[
\begin{array}{*{6}{E}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though the answer is pretty useful and I upvoted it, what I really need is how to draw at once the elements of that `3 x 3` block (the last zero column could be substituted by any other column with different elements). I guess a modification of that code should work, right?

Comment: @thanasissdr Your question didn't mentions this. doest it? The title is "Coloring elements of a block of a matrix" and the first line of the body is "Assume I have the matrix". I assumed you have the matrix and provided the answer. If you meant something different you should have stated that clearly from the beginning.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I tried to edit the question.

Comment: Where does the question say that positive elements should be colored?

Comment: @egreg Check the edit history. Original phrasing " I want to draw in red color the elements of the 3 x 3 block which are not zero". Since entries were non negative, I assumed not zero meant possitive.

Comment: @thanasissdr No problem. I updated my answer with another option.

Comment: This answer is really nice, but it doesn't work for me if I use \documentclass[]{revtex4-1} . Do you have any idea why??